# Family payment method for Google Family Link

Tags: google-play-store, in-app-purchase, google-family-link

I'm trying to set up in-app purchases for my child's Android game. We use Google Family Link. Google Play mandates setting up a family purchase method for our family group before allowing the first purchase.

I've attempted to follow Google Support's instructions on how to do so on the Google Play app, but the specified option doesn't seem to be available in my settings.

Can anyone provide guidance or a workaround for setting up a family purchase method?

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. "*but the specified option doesn't seem to be available in my settings*" could you [edit] and provide the link to Google Support, and which specific step you had been stuck on? Otherwise, the community might suggest the same step that you have been trying to do.